# Fetch table row by id Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have a small project on Laravel and I wanted to fetch table  rows by id and display in a Popup modal. I tried 'where' condition but it is not responding anything. How to do that? This is my Database Table (biniyojan_details)  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVd79.png
Here is my code..

///Controller///

```
public function biniyojan_popup_details(Request $request)
{

    $biniyojan_popup_details = DB::table('biniyojan_details')
    ->leftJoin('biniyojan','biniyojan.biniyojan_id','biniyojan_details.biniyojan_id')
    ->select('biniyojan_details.*','biniyojan.biniyojan_id','biniyojan.date','biniyojan.ab','biniyojan.behora')
    ->where('biniyojan_details.details_id', '=', 'biniyojan_details.biniyojan_id')
    ->get();
    return response()->json(['biniyojan_popup_details' => $biniyojan_popup_details]);
}
```

///Popup modal script///

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.view_btn').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
          
            var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('.id').text();

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: " {{ route('biniyojan_popup_details') }}",
                data: {

                    'checking_viewbtn': true,
                    'id': id,
                },
                //success: function(response){


                success: function(data) {
                    var html = '';
                    var biniyojan_popup_details = data.biniyojan_popup_details;
                    if (biniyojan_popup_details.length > 0) {
                        for (let i = 0; i < biniyojan_popup_details.length; i++) {
                            html += `

                                    

                                    <table id="example" border="1"  style=" width:50% ; " class="table table-hover table-wrapper-scroll-y my-custom-scrollbar">
                        <thead class="text-white bg-primary" style="font-size: 14px;">
                            <tr><th>` + biniyojan_popup_details[i]['biniyojan_id'] + `</th>
                                <th>शिर्षक</th>
                                <th>डेबिट</th>
                                <th>क्रेडिट</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody class="text-dark" style="font-size: 14px;">
                            <tr>
                            <td>` + biniyojan_popup_details[i]['kriyakalap'] + `</td>
                            <td id="bujet">` + biniyojan_popup_details[i]['cash'] + `</td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                            <td>` + biniyojan_popup_details[i]['debit_credit_type'] + `</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td id="">` + biniyojan_popup_details[i]['cash'] + `</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="text-white bg-secondary" style="font-size: 14px;">
                                <td style="font-weight:bold;">Total</td>
                                <td style="font-weight:bold;">` + biniyojan_popup_details[i]['cash'] + `</td>
                                <td style="font-weight:bold;">` + biniyojan_popup_details[i]['cash'] + `</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    
                                    `;
                        }
                    } else {
                        html += `
                                    <tr>
                                    <td colspan = "9" >  Data not Found! </td> 
                                    </tr>
                                    `;
                    }
                    $(".modal-body").html(html);
                    $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show');
                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `where('biniyojan_details.details_id', '=', 'biniyojan_details.biniyojan_id')` Have you made sure data exists in your table where the `details_id` is the same as `biniyojan_id`?

Comment: Have you checked the response returned in the network tab? does it have data?

Answer (score 0):

**I'm sorry guys, I modified the select query and it works.**

```
public function biniyojan_popup_details(Request $request) {

  $biniyojan_popup_details = BiniyojanDetails :: where('biniyojan_id',$request->id)->get();
  return response()->json(['biniyojan_popup_details' => $biniyojan_popup_details]);

}
```